# Multiple conditions for if statement unix

Tags: unix, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

i want to make an if statement with multiple conditions, but is not working, I tested it. Every LOC variable contains an integer number. I think the problem is the syntax. I'm doing a bash script.

```
if ((([ "$LOC_B_REF" -lt "$LOC_A_Q" ] && [ "$LOC_A_Q" -lt "$LOC_A_REF" ]) && [ "$LOC_B_REF" -gt "$LOC_B_Q" ]) && [ "$LOC_B_Q" -gt "$LOC_A_REF" ])

then

###do my thing 

fi
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: I think there is a confusion here, you are not writing in Unix or Linux mint, you are working with a shell script. Those come in many flavors too, like Bourne shell, Bash, C shell, Korn shell etc. Depending on the one you are using you'll have to follow a different syntax.

Comment: Bash is a Unix shell, but you could very well be using the others too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Bash, use double parentheses:

```
    if [[ "$VAR1" == "$VAR2" && "$VAR3" == "$VAR4" ]]; then
               ## Code here
    fi
```

Comment: At least in US usage, these `()` are parentheses, these `[]` are (square) brackets, and these `{}` are (curly) braces. I know the terminology varies.